# Count number of instances of a string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, `X`. Each entry `x_i` in `X` is one from a set of possible strings `Y`. How can I count the number of instances of string `y_j` in `X`?

Answer (score 2):

A solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/3419103):

```py
from collections import Counter
X = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
print Counter(X).items()
```

Output:

```
[('blue', 3), ('yellow', 1), ('red', 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't know the set `Y` in advance?

Comment: For this solution you don't need to know ```Y```.